# How can I pass in the "controller as xx" parameter xx into a directive?

Tags: angularjs

In my code I currently have this:

```
<button id="retrieveButton"
   ng-disabled="!home.forms.grid.$pristine"
   ng-click="exam.retrieve(exam.configService.admin.examStatusId, exam.configService.admin.examTypeId, 1)">
   Retrieve
   <span class="fa fa-fw mlr75"
      ng-class="{'fa-spin fa-spinner': exam.stateService.action['retrieve'], 'fa-download': !exam.stateService.action['retrieve'] }">
   </span>
</button>
```

and

```
<button id="retrieveButton"
   ng-disabled="!home.forms.grid.$pristine || content.stateService.action['init']"
   ng-click="content.retrieve(content.configService.admin.contentCreatedBy, content.configService.admin.contentModifiedBy, content.configService.admin.contentStatusId, content.configService.admin.contentTypeId, 1  )">
   Retrieve
   <span class="fa fa-fw mlr75"
      ng-class="{'fa-spin fa-spinner': content.stateService.action['retrieve'], 'fa-download': !content.stateService.action['retrieve'] }">
   </span>
</button>
```

and more ..  with all being the same except for exam .. content etc which come from the controller as xxxx.

I want to create a directive that I can use to replace the code with a common template. Here is what I created:

```
app.directive('adminRetrieveButton', ['stateService', function (stateService) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<button id='retrieveButton'\
                           ng-disabled='!home.forms.grid.$pristine'\
                           ng-click='exam.retrieve(exam.configService.admin.examStatusId, exam.configService.admin.examTypeId, 1)' >Retrieve\
                   <span class='fa fa-fw mlr75'\
                           ng-class='{\"fa-spin fa-spinner\": exam.stateService.action[\"retrieve\"], \"fa-download\": !exam.stateService.action[\"retrieve\"] }' >\
                            </span>\
                        </button>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
            scope.entity = attrs["entity"];
        }
    };
}]);
```

I think this will do the job but how can I pass in the exam or content or ..  which is I think the same as $scope.exam or $scope.content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the controller in as an attribute on your directive.

```
<admin-retrieve-button ctrl="exam"></admin-retrieve-button>
```

Then in your directive you would have to do:

```
return {
  scope: {ctrl: '=' }
  ...
}
```

In your template you can access the controller with `ctrl`

```
<button id='retrieveButton' ng-click='ctrl.retrieve( ... , 1)'>
```

Comment: Thanks rob. Should I completely replace my "scope: true" with what you wrote?

Comment: yeah. although setting the scope to an object instead of setting it to true can cause some different behavior. Here is an article that explains the difference http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/